# VB Radio button and Combo Box Flash

Tags: vb.net, combobox, radio-button

I have written a small piece of code to change the display member of my combo box when a radio button is selected. The only problem I'm having is that when I switch between the radio buttons the combo box disappears then comes back a second later, is there any way of resolving this problem.

Private Sub SearchOptionChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RBExchange.CheckedChanged, RBPostcode.CheckedChanged

```
    Dim RB As RadioButton = CType(sender, RadioButton)
    If RB.Name = "RBExchange" AndAlso RB.Checked Then
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Exchange"
        ComboBox1.Text = ""

    ElseIf RB.Name = "RBPostcode" AndAlso RB.Checked Then
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Postcode"
        ComboBox1.Text = ""

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: you might want to show the code, otherwise we are guessing at what you are doing.  As per [Ask]

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: What is the datasource?  A second (if meant literally) sounds like a long time, but changing the DisplayMember does mean that the LB has to repaint the visible contents.  How many elements in the DataSource?  Also, if you used the TAG property of the RBs to store the member string, you could get reduce that block of code to 1-2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following to reproduce your issue and it only happens when DropDownStyle is set to Simple. So if possible set DropDownStyle to DropDown.

Note I used 5,000 items and no blinking, jumped to 10,000 and the blinking was there so in addition to the suggestion above consider if possible to reduce how many items in the ComboBox if business logic allows.

Test used and note that even SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout did not help when DropDownStyle is set to Simple.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim ItemList As New List(Of item)

        For x As Integer = 0 To 50000

            ItemList.Add(New item With
                         {
                             .Exchange = "E" & x.ToString,
                             .PostCode = "P" & x.ToString
                         })
        Next

        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Exchange"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ItemList

    End Sub
    Private Sub RBExchange_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles RBExchange.CheckedChanged, RBPostcode.CheckedChanged

        Dim RB As RadioButton = CType(sender, RadioButton)
        RB.SuspendLayout()
        If RB.Name = "RBExchange" AndAlso RB.Checked Then
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Exchange"
            ComboBox1.Text = ""

        ElseIf RB.Name = "RBPostcode" AndAlso RB.Checked Then
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Postcode"
            ComboBox1.Text = ""
        End If
        RB.ResumeLayout()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class item
    Public Property Exchange
    Public Property PostCode
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to have sorted the problem.